# Laplace transform of numerical data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Trying to compute the Laplace transform of my data, like I would with the FFT of my data. When I try

```
laplace(data)
```

I get the error

```
Undefined function 'laplace' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

But whatever I change "data" to I get the same error. Does Laplace not work this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`laplace()`](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/laplace.html) is a **symbolic** function. Which means that it calculates a Laplace transformation fo a given, symbolic, input. I presume your data is numeric, and not symbolic, hence you get the error: `laplace` is only defined for symbolics, and not for `'double'`, i.e. numeric, values.

The Fourier transform equivalent is also not `fft()`, but rather `fourier()`. The former acts for numerical input, the latter for symbolic input. MATLAB currently has no implementation for a numerical Laplace transform.

Comment: What do you mean by symbolic? Like does it need an equation for the data?

Comment: @user2587726 read the linked documentation, that sums it up nicely. Basically you can take the Laplace transform of a given formula, e.g. `cos(x)`, but not of a list of numbers. The Laplace transform is a very difficult problem numerically speaking, as opposed to the Fourier transform which has a simple, closed-form expression for every possible input list of numbers. The Laplace transform OTOH heavily depends on which function the underlying data is representing.