# Laplace transform of equation from "fit"

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

This is a follow-up on a previous question by myself: [Laplace transform of numerical data in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59632404/laplace-transform-of-numerical-data-in-matlab)

---

I have experimentally collected data, and want to take a Laplace transformation of that. However, `laplace()` needs a model/equation. I find a fit equation to model my data from:

```
[up,lo] = envelope(dat);

x = 1:length(up);
x = x';

f = fit(x,up,'poly3');
```

Then for my Laplace transform I need to I pass the output of

```
f = fit(x,up,'poly3');
```

into

```
syms f
laplace(f)
```

However at the moment this spits out the transform of `f`:

```
laplace(f)

ans =

1/s^2
```

If this is `f`

```
f = 

     Linear model Poly3:
     f(x) = p1*x^3 + p2*x^2 + p3*x + p4
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       p1 =   1.772e-12  (1.593e-12, 1.951e-12)
       p2 =  -2.211e-08  (-2.483e-08, -1.939e-08)
       p3 =   2.847e-05  (1.676e-05, 4.017e-05)
       p4 =      0.2762  (0.2627, 0.2897)
```

How do I find the Laplace transform of `f`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the output of `fit`, but your symbolic variable at least should be `x`, as that's your dependent variable. You can then build up the `f` yourself:

```
p1 =   1.772e-12;
p2 =  -2.211e-08;
p3 =   2.847e-05;
p4 =      0.2762;

syms x

f = p1*x.^3 + p2*x.^2 + p3*x + p4;

laplace(f)
ans =

(8402860860456175*((50949907131585781563392*s)/5251788037785109375 + 1))/(295147905179352825856*s^2) - 6682337467919863/(151115727451828646838272*s^3) + 26323556995364325/(2475880078570760549798248448*s^4)
```

`fit()` gives you a `fitobject` type variable, which, if I understand [its documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fit.html) correctly, can be accessed as a structure. This means that you should be able to programmatically use the fitted parameters to build your function of symbolic `x`.